# EF Core, append to predicate builder in Any condition

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core, predicatebuilder

I'm trying to merge two predicates in then Any clause of the following code, but i cannot find a way to do this.

```
private static Expression<Func<Order, bool>> BuildWhereExpression(DataFilterOrder filter, AppDbContext dbContext)
{

var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Order>();

var confirmationPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<HConfirmation>();

if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.ConfirmationNumber))
{
  confirmationPredicate = confirmationPredicate.And(r =>
  r.Confirmation.Document.Number == filter.ConfirmationNumber);
}
if (filter.ConfirmationDateFrom != null)
{
  confirmationPredicate = confirmationPredicate.And(r =>
  r.Confirmation.Document.Date >= filter.ConfirmationDateFrom);
}
.....


predicate = predicate.And(o =>
   dbContext.Confirmations
   .Join(
     dbContext.DocumentHierarchies,
     c => c.DocumentId,
     h => h.ChildDocumentId,
     (c, h) => new HConfirmation { Confirmation = c, Hierarchy = h })
   .Any(r => r.Hierarchy.ParentDocumentId == o.DocumentId && 
   ???confirmationPredicate???)

  return predicate;
}
....

// called by

  var wherePredicate = BuildWhereExpression(filter, dbContext);


  var list = await dbContext.Orders
    .Where(wherePredicate)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Any help? Thanks very much.

`PredicateBuilder` class:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
    {

        // Creates a predicate that evaluates to true.        
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return param => true; }

        // Creates a predicate that evaluates to false.        
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return param => false; }

        // Creates a predicate expression from the specified lambda expression.        
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) { return predicate; }
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Create1<T, K>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, K obj) { return predicate; }

        // Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "and".        
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
        {
            return first.Compose(second, Expression.AndAlso);
        }

        // Combines the first predicate with the second using the logical "or".        
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> first, Expression<Func<T, bool>> second)
        {
            return first.Compose(second, Expression.OrElse);
        }

        // Negates the predicate.        
        public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            var negated = Expression.Not(expression.Body);
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(negated, expression.Parameters);
        }

        // Combines the first expression with the second using the specified merge function.        
        static Expression<T> Compose<T>(this Expression<T> first, Expression<T> second, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
        {
            // zip parameters (map from parameters of second to parameters of first)
            var map = first.Parameters
                .Select((f, i) => new { f, s = second.Parameters[i] })
                .ToDictionary(p => p.s, p => p.f);

            // replace parameters in the second lambda expression with the parameters in the first
            var secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body);

            // create a merged lambda expression with parameters from the first expression
            return Expression.Lambda<T>(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters);
        }

        class ParameterRebinder : ExpressionVisitor
        {
            readonly Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map;

            ParameterRebinder(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map)
            {
                this.map = map ?? new Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression>();
            }

            public static Expression ReplaceParameters(Dictionary<ParameterExpression, ParameterExpression> map, Expression exp)
            {
                return new ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp);
            }

            protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression p)
            {
                ParameterExpression replacement;
                if (map.TryGetValue(p, out replacement))
                {
                    p = replacement;
                }
                return base.VisitParameter(p);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Any(confirmationPredicate.And(r => r.Hierarchy.ParentDocumentId == o.DocumentId))`

Comment: @IvanStoev Throws an exception: System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.InstanceMethodCallExpression1' to type 'System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression'.
  Stack Trace: 
    ExpressionExtensions.UnwrapLambdaFromQuote(Expression expression)

Comment: Not so easy but doable. Which is signature of calling method (dbContext, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, tried to simplify solution, but looks like it is needed to build `Any` part dynamically. Sorry not tested and some small mistakes can be here.

```cs
private static Expression<Func<Order, bool>> BuildWhereExpression(DataFilterOrder filter, AppDbContext dbContext)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.True<Order>();

    var confirmationPredicate = PredicateBuilder.True<HConfirmation>();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filter.ConfirmationNumber))
    {
        confirmationPredicate = confirmationPredicate.And(r =>
        r.Confirmation.Document.Number == filter.ConfirmationNumber);
    }
    if (filter.ConfirmationDateFrom != null)
    {
        confirmationPredicate = confirmationPredicate.And(r =>
        r.Confirmation.Document.Date >= filter.ConfirmationDateFrom);
    }
    .....

    // we can write this query separately
    var confirmations = dbContext.Confirmations
        .Join(dbContext.DocumentHierarchies,
            c => c.DocumentId,
            h => h.ChildDocumentId,
            (c, h) => new HConfirmation { Confirmation = c, Hierarchy = h }
        );

    var orderParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Order), "o");
    var hConfirmationParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(HConfirmation), "r");

    // r.Hierarchy.ParentDocumentId == o.DocumentId
    var anyPredicate = (Expression)Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(Expression.Property(hConfirmationParam, "Hierarchy"), "ParentDocumentId"),
        Expression.Property(orderParam, "DocumentId"));

    // r.Confirmation
    var confirmationAccess = Expression.Property(hConfirmationParam, "Confirmation");
    // correcting confirmation predicate
    var confirmationPredicateCorrected = ExpressionReplacer.GetBody(confirmationPredicate, confirmationAccess);

    // r.Hierarchy.ParentDocumentId == o.DocumentId && confirmationPredicateCorrected
    anyPredicate = Expression.AndAlso(anyPredicate, confirmationPredicateCorrected);
    // r => r.Hierarchy.ParentDocumentId == o.DocumentId && confirmationPredicateCorrected
    var anyLambda = Expression.Lambda(anyPredicate, hConfirmationParam);

    var anyCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Any", new [] { typeof(HConfirmation) }, confirmations.Expression, Expression.Quote(anyLambda));

    var additionalPredicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Order, bool>>(anyCall, orderParam);

    predicate = predicate.And(additionalPredicate);

    return predicate;
}
```

Anyawy, additional helper class is needed:

```cs
public class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
{
    readonly IDictionary<Expression, Expression> _replaceMap;

    public ExpressionReplacer(IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
    {
        _replaceMap = replaceMap ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(replaceMap));
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp != null && _replaceMap.TryGetValue(exp, out var replacement))
            return replacement;
        return base.Visit(exp);
    }

    public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, Expression toReplace, Expression toExpr)
    {
        return new ExpressionReplacer(new Dictionary<Expression, Expression> { { toReplace, toExpr } }).Visit(expr);
    }

    public static Expression Replace(Expression expr, IDictionary<Expression, Expression> replaceMap)
    {
        return new ExpressionReplacer(replaceMap).Visit(expr);
    }

    public static Expression GetBody(LambdaExpression lambda, params Expression[] toReplace)
    {
        if (lambda.Parameters.Count != toReplace.Length)
            throw new InvalidOperationException();

        return new ExpressionReplacer(Enumerable.Range(0, lambda.Parameters.Count)
            .ToDictionary(i => (Expression) lambda.Parameters[i], i => toReplace[i])).Visit(lambda.Body);
    }
}
```

Strongly recommend this extension for Expression Tree visualization and debugging: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1232914.ReadableExpressionsVisualizers